# Sql Server Migration from 2005 to 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

We are planning to migrate sql server from 2005 to 2008.We have decided to create user logins manually instead of migrating from 2005 server, as we have different applications (windows services) accessing our DBs.

Intention behind is , we want to categorize entires in Activity Monitor based on user login.So that we can identify which process consuming more DB reources.

Please suggest whether this is the best way or not and what is the maximum no of user login can be created on Database.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Separating logins for each different service is a good idea IMO to isolate the potential problems. The technical limit is 32767 for user connections but no one should be creating that many logins.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx